# Play Framework : Cannot find the install command

Tags: java, maven, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to install the maven module for play framework 2.1.1 and i cannot figure out why "install" command is not available :

From a project :

```
play install maven

[info] Loading project definition from C:\someproject
[info] Set current project to SomeProject(in build file:/C:\someproject)
[error] Not a valid command: install (similar: initialize, inspect, shell)
[error] Expected '/'
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: install (similar: initialize, dist, stage)
[error] install
[error]        ^
```

From any directory :

```
play install maven
       _            _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
|  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
|_|            |__/ 

play! 2.1.1 (using Java 1.7.0_21 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org


This is not a play application!

Use `play new` to create a new Play application in the current directory,
 or go to an existing application and launch the development console using `play`
.

You can also browse the complete documentation at http://www.playframework.org.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `install` command is for Play 1.x only, as are the modules listed the [module directory](http://www.playframework.com/modules). There are some [modules for 2.1.1](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Modules).

To install modules in Play 2.x projects, you have to add them as dependencies in `project/Build.scala`. The module's readme should tell you to do to get it running.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have to say that the separation between 1.x and 2.x is not that obvious for the new comers reading documentations / howtos.

Comment: @user2686218 Yeah I agree with that, it got me a few times too. They really changed a lot between 1.x and 2.x. Especially when you google something you always have to look twice to make sure it's for the right version.